# Finding one of my colleagues a bit annoying

Tags: colleagues

He is a nice guy generally, but he has this really annoying trait of wanting to always be right and then arguing for the sake of being right.

I have treated him professionally, sometimes letting him win so that I do not need to entertain the argument further, but at times it irritates me on topics where I think he is being naive.

Aside from just taking in one ear than out the other, what other mechanisms are there to cope with it?

Comment: Are these arguments on work-related matters, or are they based on external topics?

Comment: Everything, it seems as though it is his personality trait. Sometimes talks in a patronising way, which gets on my nerves. Not sure if he realises it.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to like your colleagues, and many of us have co-workers who [might annoy us](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/73618/how-do-i-create-an-office-friendly-silence-grenade).

The coping mechanism obviously depends on the inter-personal dynamic, so you can either ignore the problem, or use diversionary tactics to avoid the arguments.

If the arguments are work related, you can involve other people to mediate (if needed).  If your co-worker is often wrong in his arguments (and it's a working environment issue), you can use this as a teaching exercise and work through the reasoning with him/her (just being told you're wrong doesn't really teach you much).

Answer (score 0):

As your comment reflect, the person argues on anything and he is annoying.
If you can't stand then, the most logical thing to do is to engage in discussion only when your work demands it.

> *I have treated him professionally, sometimes letting him win so that I do not need to entertain the argument further*

This is not professional at all. Logic and the piece of work that you are doing precede here. What I mean by that is to carefully present your analysis during an argument and concentrate only on that. Every work related discussion need a prior study and analysis for the specific problem. If the person under question is blindly shooting down all what you say, I see no point in discussing with them further. Ask for advise from your boss/manager and if possible try to have them present during the discussion.

Comment: Some people see their intelligence as a core personality trait and will argue just to prove themselves correct, not to examine a topic from all angles, which is the healthy thing to do. Managing people includes letting them play with their toys. The colleague's arguments are his toys.

Comment: @rath As a professional, I would concentrate only on the task and wouldn't try to dissipate my attention if the other person is fooling around or not. There may be a million ways to play games, but to get the job done should be the priority.